# MySQl navicat :: Error in adding parameters

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, parameters, navicat

```
 CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER PROCEDURE `NewProc`(IN `pName` varchar)
BEGIN
    SELECT * from ss

END;;
```

when  I try to save this SP using navicat to MySql Db i face syntax error problem at line number 1, when i delete the parameter, SP is saved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the length of **pName** in your parameter.

Try this:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `NewProc`$$

CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER PROCEDURE `NewProc`(IN `pName` VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM ss;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```